# Java - Is it possible to instance for a UserDefined Class or java primitive types

Tags: java, variables

I have a user defined class like the following,

```
package com.hexgen.tools;

public class UserDefinedParams {
    private String dataType="";
    private String isArray="";
    public String getDataType() {
        return dataType;
    }
    public void setDataType(String dataType) {
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }
    public String getIsArray() {
        return isArray;
    }
    public void setIsArray(String isArray) {
        this.isArray = isArray;
    }

}
```

`dataType` and `isArray` the values for this if dataType -> `this may have userdefined pojo class or java primitive type` and if isArray ->`this will have Y or N`. based on this how to create something like:

if dataType `someUserDefinedPOJO` and isArray `Y`

-> `someUserDefinedPOJO[] obj = new someUserDefinedPOJO();`

```
vise versa for java primitive types too.
```

`is it possible through reflection in java?`

How to do this?

Best Regards

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this ? Do you want to add the dynamic variables and the corresponding code to your source code ?

Comment: I'd suggest you have a look at **reflection** in Java. However, if this is an important functionality in your program, you will be much easier off with a weak typed programming language.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following, but note that `Object` can store pretty much anything. Regardless, you'd be much better off redesigning your program such that what you're trying to do is no longer required.

Comment: i have edited my question, hope this would make sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just use a `HashMap<String,Object>` , 
you can define all your variables in there, for example:

```
HashMap<String,Object> map=new HashMap<String,Object>();
map.put("myVarName",new Object());

System.out.printlb(map.get("myVarName"));
```

Comment: this is when we know what is going to come, if so what is the need for me to create instance dynamically and create it at source level itself

Comment: its the best imitation of dynamic variables, you can put any name that comes from any place, its a string

Answer (score 1):

There are no dynamic variables in Java. Java variables have to be declared in the source code.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you should use an array, a List or a Map; e.g.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/dynamic-variable-names-in-java).

```
int n[] = new int[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    n[i] = 5;
}

List<Integer> n = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    n.add(5);
}

Map<String, Integer> n = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    n.put("n" + i, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into java reflection. But this has already posted on SO.

[Read link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537363/how-to-create-new-variable-in-java-dynamically)

[Read link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192534/is-there-away-to-generate-variables-names-dynamically-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible route is to go with generics:

```
public class CustomVariable<E> {
    private E var;

    public CustomVariable<E>(E value){
        var = value;
    }
}
```

But I wouldn't know about arrays though.