# Declaring class level variables JAVA

Tags: java

Is it possible to declare a class level variable from within a method?

I'm simply trying to create a static counter, but I only want to create it if needed.  The class calling it should live longer than the function itself.

My need for this is rare, but I'm interested if it would work.

Comment: Just pass around a variable to methods that need it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create new variable in java dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537363/how-to-create-new-variable-in-java-dynamically)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Java support static variables inside a function to keep values between invocations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19062467/does-java-support-static-variables-inside-a-function-to-keep-values-between-invo)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not it is not possible to *declare* class level field, unless you're doing some metaprogramming stuff like insane bytecode level modification that wouldn't pay for itself. All declaration is done at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

"Is it possible to declare a class level variable from within a method?"

If literally - yes :) it is possible with method-local classes :

```
void method() {
    class LocalClass {
        private Object variable;
    }
}
```

Comment: `private` seems somewhat pointless and `static` might be required (`"create a static counter"`).

Comment: Agree. I printed 'private' just habitually. But it is not so pointless as it seems. There is a namespace inside the method so private modifier can be used to hide the variable from another method local classes. Method local inner classes cant be static so they cant have static fields.

Comment: "to hide the variable from another method local classes" - sorry, it is better to say "from other classes except the same method local classes".

Comment: So if they can't be static, it won't work to create a static counter with, right? I'm not sure I understood the other part. Did you mean that it if it's private, classes inheriting that method don't have access to it?

Comment: THis doesn't answer the question. He wants a `static.`

Comment: Im sorry for missunderstanding, but i really tried to joke. Thought it will be funny. I know that it is not place for such things. Sorry again for irrelevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

'static ... when needed' is a contradiction in terms. The answer is 'no'.